# Worklight: Do the legal documents gets installed with the app?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Environment: Worklight 6.1.0.2

We have created a hybrid app using Worklight 6.1 for android, iOS and windows8 platform. We would like to include license documents and notices files as part of the app. To do this, we would like to know, if including these documents inside the "legal" folder (under application name folder) and installing the app on the device, will also install these license documents on the device ?

I browse through the android app, but didn't found these documents as part of the build.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

The legal folder is not part of the generated Android project because it has no value there. The native project will become your .apk - the file that you distribute to your end-users. The license is of no use there; your customer cannot see it.